# Spring Security configuration with the login form

Tags: spring-boot-configuration

It showing me the defult Login form and my login form i use the defult User name und passowrd to login to time. in the first time it sowing me my login form and when i try to login in the same default username and password it rturn alwas to the second login form with code stat:302. (i saved employee in the database but it givs me alwas err)

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeDao employeeDao;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password 
         from employees where username=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority from employees where username=?")
        .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
        .csrf().disable()
             .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
             .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true").defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true)
        .and()  
             .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout=true") ;


    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
     @GetMapping({"/","/login"}) 
     public String LoginForm() { return "login";}

     @GetMapping("/home")
     public String showhome(Model model) { return "index";}
```

My Entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "fullname", nullable = false)
    private String fullname;

    @Column(name = "authority", nullable = false)
    private String authority;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Role> roles;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }

    public void setFullname(String fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    public String getAuthority() {
        return authority;
    }

    public void setAuthority(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

My Login form:

```
 <div class="divLogin" align="center">
        <h1 clase="text-center">Login Page</h1>
        <form class="addForm" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">               
            <fieldset>
                <legend lase="text-center">Please Login</legend>

                  <input class="inputForm" type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>        

                  <input class="inputForm" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Passowrd"/>    

                <div class="divBottonLogin" align="center">
                  <button class="botten" type="submit">Log in</button>
                </div> 
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not sure what are you asking for

Comment: @Narvalex i want to use my login form to login but i got alwas first the default login form and i can connect my login with mysql database